# Clojure - lazily reading frames with gloss

Tags: clojure, io

I want to turn an `InputStream` to a seq of frames. If I correctly understand the code, `gloss.io/lazy-decode-all` eagerly consumes its second argument, which is not an option in my case.

I've found a way to do this with `aleph/input-stream->channel`, `decode-channel` and `lamina.core.operators/channel->lazy-seq`, but it looks a bit too much for such a common task. Also I'm a bit concerned with performance in this scenario: the app will be fed several gigabytes of data.

I could manually read the frames into `ByteBuffer`s and `decode` them, but they have dynamic length, so I'll duplicate much of the logic in gloss.

Is there some concise way to lazily decode the stream?